# the leak Activity monitor is reliable?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

I  Write my iphone app.
I checked the leak with leak instrument when I push and pop a ViewController. it can't find any red tip.
But  I check the app with the same method. the memory of the app increased slowly.

which is reliable. My app leak?

thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Not all losses of memory are leaks, just ones that there is no pointer to.  Try Heapshot Analysis, bbum has a great [tutorial here](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17).  I have used Heapshot many times to great advantage, many thanks to bum.

The leaks tool is not foolproof, it is a good start.

Also use the LLVM static analyzer and fix all of it's warnings.